# Show parent viewcontroller portrait when navigate from child view

Tags: ios5, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation, portrait

When i come back to parent viewcontroller its not rotate as portrait. my problem is when i go back to parent viewcontroller its orientation is still in PortraitUpsidedown.

And also my app support only in portrait mode, except in one viewController.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: did you check viewWillLayoutSubviews are getting fired...

Comment: @johnson Mathew yes this method is fired.